# Split by days a big nagios log file

Tags: regex, logging, sed, unix-timestamp, nagios

I have a Nagios log file, of 6G (a month of logging) and I want to split it in one file for each day. Meaning that from 1 file: nagios.log to obtain files: nagios-2014-10-01.log to nagios-2014-10-31.log (31 files).

Each line begin with a UNIX timestamp as:

```
[1414709999] EXTERNAL COMMAND: PROCESS_SERVICE_CHECK_RESULT;servername;DiskTime;0;OK: \Physikalischer Datenträger(_Total)\Zeit (%): 0.479991|\Physikalischer Datenträger(_Total)\Zeit (%)=0.47999;55;90
```

So I have to find a way to grep all lines from a specific day and move them to a separate file.
I've already tried with SED and GREP, but I can't find a way to REGEX this kind of range of timestamp.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Share what you have tried; explain what you expect for a narrowed set of sample input (e.g. a few entries for just a few days); and describe where what you have tried falls short.  Some fine tuning may just be needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
 d=2014-10-01
 awk -v t=$(date -d $d +"%s") -F '[\[\]]' '$2 >= t {print}' nagios.log > nagios-${d}.log
```